# trying to get both the userID and the ID of the profile where the clicked on the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

I am designing an app that lets one facebook user commission another user. I'm new to the facebook API, but I'm doing my best - hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

The app does the following:

1) Once authorized, it creates a tab on your timeline.
2) Then another facebook user clicks on this tab.
3) once they authorize and give permission, I want to capture the user id of the logged in user (this is easy) and the ID of the profile on which they clicked to install the app (this I can't do). I'm sending these off to a MySQL server.

So am I capturing two distinct userIDs? Or a userID and a pageID?  any help very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well you simply can't add applications to a user's profile.  So what you are seeing is a PAGE_ID (assuming you mean that the application was installed on a **page's timeline**), and a USER_ID.

You'll find all this information in the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) that is passed to the page. Once you have decoded this `signed_request` the page info is in the `page` parameter -

> **page** - A JSON object containing the page id string, the liked boolean (set to true if the user has liked the page, false if not) and the admin boolean (set to true if the user is an admin of the page, false if they're not). This field is only present if your app is being loaded within a Page Tab.

And the user info is in the `user` parameter -

> **user** - A JSON object containing the locale string, country string and the age object. See the Age Object table for actual min and max values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I get that there's a difference between pages and profiles. I'm going to implement the signed_request method for pages. But I have a larger question. When a user installs an app and adds it to their timeline, is there any way for me to capture their id (USER1_ID) when someone else (USER2_ID) clicks on the application? in this example, user2 is the one logged in, user1 is the one who has the app on their timeline.

Comment: **You can't install applications on users timelines...**

Comment: What you will be able to do, is when someone installs your application on their **page's timeline**, you store their user_id against their page_id.  Then when you read the signed_request and extract the page_id, you can match it to the user_id that installed the application (one of the page's administrators)